# What is the best approach to bind to different port / each port has different handler in Netty?,

Tags: java, netty

I want to build an application based on Netty, but need to bind to different ports at the same time, and each port needs to have a different handler logic. How to do this in Netty?

I searched online, and know that I can probably do bind(host,port) multiple times, but that stills mean all ports will use the same handler pipeline.

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't think that's true. Handlers are attached to channels, they aren't global.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply create several `ServerBootstrap` instances using a single `ChannelFactory`. For example:

```
    NioServerSocketChannelFactory factory = new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
            Executors.newCachedThreadPool(), Executors.newCachedThreadPool());

    ServerBootstrap bootstrap1 = new ServerBootstrap(factory);
    bootstrap1.setPipelineFactory(...);
    bootstrap1.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port1));

    ServerBootstrap bootstrap2 = new ServerBootstrap(factory);
    bootstrap2.setPipelineFactory(...);
    bootstrap2.bind(new InetSocketAddress(port2));
```

Or, you can dynamically modify the pipeline. For example in the `channelBound`callback:

```
@Override
public void channelBound(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
    ctx.getPipeline().addLast("new", new SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler() {
        @Override
        public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
             ...
        }
    });
}
```